# IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, android-sqlite

How do I apply this([Click This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-it)) to my application? Thank you!

**Log Cat:**

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at com.example.workhours.view_hours$1.onSwiped(view_hours.java:65)
```

**Code:**

**This is the line where the error occurred:**

(line: 65) final String x = listShift.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getDate();

> Additional Information:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{


ArrayList<newNote> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: that says that your `lifshift` is empty, and you are trying to access the element which is not there.

Comment: listShift seems to be an empty list

Comment: How do I go about fixing that exactly? this is what I did: ArrayList<newNote> list;                  and on the oncreate method I put      "list = new ArrayList<>();"

Comment: Thank you! But it seems like my list is empty. Do you know how I can initialize my list?

Comment: You have to put some data into liftShift.

Comment: I did exactly that! Thank you ! it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:Print/Check the value returned by viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()

Step 2:Check the size of List by **listShift.size()**

Reason why is it happening:

1. Value of  viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() < 0
2. Value of  viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() > listShift.size()
3. List is empty

Comment: I did "listShift.size()" and it returned 0

Comment: How do I fix that please. I am not sure. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you I fixed it! what I did was "listShift = myDb.viewAllHours();"

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can handle the exception, use ternary operator:

```
final String x = listShift.size() < viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()+1 ? null: listShift.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getDate();
```

Comment: Thank you! But it seems like my list is empty. Do you know how I can initialize my list?

Comment: Thank you I fixed it! what I did was "listShift = myDb.viewAllHours();"

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize adapter if list is not empty. The Code that initializing adapter, adding list is not empty check worked me.

```
var list = ArrayList<String>()
list.add(item)
if(listArr.isNotEmpty()){
     adapter = Adapter(listArr)
}
```